# Error:(28) Error parsing XML: no element found

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this error, and I do not know how to fix it. The error occurred when I tried to add a third party library XML element, but I can not solve it.

Some places tell me that it is an Android Studio problem and that it is fixed by restarting the program and I did that and it did not solve the problem. Here is the code:

```
public class HorizontalNtbActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_ntb);
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 5;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(final View view, final Object object) {
                return view.equals(object);
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(final View container, final int position, final Object object) {
                ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
                final View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                        getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_vp, null, false);

                final TextView txtPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_vp_item_page);
                txtPage.setText(String.format("Page #%d", position));

                container.addView(view);
                return view;
            }
        });

        final String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_preview);

        final NavigationTabBar navigationTabBar = (NavigationTabBar) findViewById(R.id.ntb_horizontal);
        final ArrayList<NavigationTabBar.Model> models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(
                new NavigationTabBar.Model.Builder(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_first),
                        Color.parseColor(colors[0]))
                        .selectedIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sixth))
                        .title("Heart")
                        .badgeTitle("NTB")
                        .build()
        );
        ...
    }
    ....
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#423752"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/PostList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <devlight.io.library.ntb.NavigationTabBar
        android:id="@+id/ntb_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:ntb_badge_gravity="top"
        app:ntb_badge_position="right"
        app:ntb_badged="true"
        app:ntb_scaled="true"
        app:ntb_tinted="true"
        app:ntb_title_mode="all"
        app:ntb_titled="true"
        app:ntb_swiped="true"/>
     ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the title of your question means you get an error with the error code 28. By Googling for this I found [this page](https://blog.udemy.com/xml-parsing-error/) stating that error code 28 means that:

> The version information wasn’t present in the XML declaration.

So to fix this error, simply add the following line above the first tag of your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Hope this helps!